# How to wire a DynamoDB stream to a kinesis stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-kinesis, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I was assuming I

- create a table and enable stream and I now have an ARN
- create a kinesis stream
- configure somewhere to tell the dynamoDb stream to write to kinesis stream

I was looking at working with https://github.com/harlow/kinesis-consumer but this reads from kinesis or can I use the ARN and use it to read right from the dynamoDB stream?

The more I look, the more I seem to think, I have to write a lambda to read dynamoDB and write to kinesis.  Is that correct?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hey can you provide a bit more of information about your target setup? do you plan to have some sort of ETL process for your dynamoDB table? AFAIK when you bound a kinesis stream to a dynamodb table, everytime you add, remove or update rows on the dynamodb a new event will be publish in the associated kinesis stream which you can consume from and use the event in whatever way you want.

maybe worth checking this one:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.KCLAdapter.Walkthrough.html

Comment: I didn't -1 you.  I hate people that do that.  Anyways @Folger Fonseca, dynamoDB streams is NOT a kinesis stream.  In fact, they make an adapter on top of the dynamoDB stream api so you can use a kinesis api on top.  kinesis stream has enhanced fanout while dynamoDB stream does  not.

Comment: you are right, we use this approach in my company to populate our DWH, but I thought the stream will behave like any other normal kinesis stream, in such a case I think there won't be another way than to have a lambda to publish to your desire stream. Thanks @Dean

Comment: Thats pretty cool! Does it still maintain the order of the records in Kinesis Data Streams as in the DynamoDB Streams?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB now support Kinesis Data Streams natively:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/kds.html

You can choose either DynamoDB Streams or Kinesis Data Streams for your Change Data Capture (CDC).

| Properties | Kinesis Data Streams for DynamoDB | DynamoDB Streams |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data retention | Up to 1 year. | 24 hours. |
| Kinesis Client Library (KCL) support | Supports KCL versions 1.X and 2.X. | Supports KCL version 1.X. |
| Number of consumers | Up to 5 simultaneous consumers per shard, or up to 20 simultaneous consumers per shard with enhanced fan-out. | Up to 2 simultaneous consumers per shard. |
| Throughput quotas | Unlimited. | Subject to throughput quotas by DynamoDB table and AWS Region. |
| Record delivery model | Pull model over HTTP using GetRecords and with enhanced fan-out, Kinesis Data Streams pushes the records over HTTP/2 by using SubscribeToShard. | Pull model over HTTP using GetRecords. |
| Ordering of records | The timestamp attribute on each stream record can be used to identify the actual order in which changes occurred in the DynamoDB table. | For each item that is modified in a DynamoDB table, the stream records appear in the same sequence as the actual modifications to the item. |
| Duplicate records | Duplicate records might occasionally appear in the stream. | No duplicate records appear in the stream. |
| Stream processing options | Process stream records using AWS Lambda, Kinesis Data Analytics, Kinesis data firehose , or AWS Glue streaming ETL. | Process stream records using AWS Lambda or DynamoDB Streams Kinesis adapter. |
| Durability level | Availability zones to provide automatic failover without interruption. | Availability zones to provide automatic failover without interruption. |

Answer (score 0):

You can use Amazon Kinesis Data Streams to capture changes to Amazon DynamoDB. According to [the AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/kds.html):

> Kinesis Data Streams captures item-level modifications in any DynamoDB table and replicates them to a Kinesis data stream. Your applications can access this stream and view item-level changes in near-real time. You can continuously capture and store terabytes of data per hour. You can take advantage of longer data retention time—and with enhanced fan-out capability, you can simultaneously reach two or more downstream applications. Other benefits include additional audit and security transparency.

Also You can enable streaming to Kinesis from your DynamoDB table.